# AVAudioPlayer not Working

Tags: objective-c, ios10, avaudioplayer

I have recorded few audio files and saved them in **NSDocumentsDirectory/Recordings**.In tableView I am showing the audio files names and its duration.In **tableView didselectMethod** I have written this method to play an audio file but it was not working . I have gone through many solutions on stackover flow all having the same approach like this.But when I tried the same my required audio file was not playing.Finally I came to sort out that when I declare that AVAudioPlayer in **@interface** it's working fine. what is the reason can I get a clear explanation.

```
 #define recordingsFolderPath [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recordings"]

    @interface MyTableViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation MyTableViewController{

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

           UITableviewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuse forIndexPath:indexPath];
           NSError *error = nil;
           NSString *path = [recordingsFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:cell.textLabel.text];
           NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
           AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
           if(!audioPlayer) {
                NSLog(@"Error %@ ",error.localizedDescription);
           }
           [audioPlayer play];
    }
```

Comment: Because the `AVAudioPlayer` defined in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is a local variable, which means it only exists within that function. Once the function call is finished the player is deallocated. Declaring it in the `@interface` as you mention declares it as a global variable. Therefore it is not deallocated until the containing class is.

Comment: yes that is right thanks for the answer. I declared it in interface and its working now.